# How to programmatically provide `queryset` to PrimaryKeyRelatedField in DRF 3

Tags: django-rest-framework

In order to have a non-readonly `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, you are required to provide a queryset that contains valid options.

How can I properly populate that queryset based on the current request (user)?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The key is to subclass `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and overload the `get_queryset` method, using the user information from the request context:

```py
class UserFilteredPrimaryKeyRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        queryset = super(UserFilteredPrimaryKeyRelatedField, self).get_queryset()
        if not request or not queryset:
            return None
        return queryset.filter(user=request.user)
```

You can then use this new serializer just like the (unfiltered) original:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related = UserFilteredPrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=MyModel.objects)
```

Whenever the serializer accesses the queryset, it will be filtered such that only objects owned by the current user are returned.

Comment: This should be marked as answer. I would only add another condition to the if: `or not request.user.is_authenticated`, so it returns None instead of an exception when no user is logged in

Comment: I'm unable to get the context in the serializer, despite overriding get_serializer_context() in the view. Any pointers on that will be really helpful.

Comment: Update: was able to get the context right, by calling get_serializer() instead of get_serializer_class(), but now the queryset on the serializer is not filtered. It just takes the default(all) queryset that is used while declaring the field on the serailizer.
Put a debugger inside of the get_queryset() in the serializer but the code does not hit that part, and I do not understand why. Any pointers will be helpful are appreciated.

Comment: For those struggling, here is a simple example: https://medium.com/django-rest-framework/limit-related-data-choices-with-django-rest-framework-c54e96f5815e

Comment: `not queryset` will actually perform the query in full and check whether there are any items in it, which may be very slow! Use `queryset is None` instead to check whether there IS a queryset!

Answer (score -13):

View has a

```
self.request.user
```

attribute which you can then use to fetch user related queryset
eg

```
queryset = Products.objects.get(customer=self.request.user)
```

Comment: How do you access the view in the class level of the serializer?

Comment: You can't. You could override the __init__ of the Serializer class to get the view from self.context or even modify the view to pass the logged-in user to the serializer context and use that. The second approach is better because you can test the Serializer individually without requiring to create a view.

Comment: @Fatima request object is not directly exposed in Serializer, work around is context.