# Django Rest Framework: Filtering in Read/Write Related Field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have `User`s and `Group`s, where `Group`s are a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` on `User`s. When writing a `User`, I only want to assign it to `Group`s the current user is in. When retrieving a `User`, I only want to show the `Group`s that it has in common with the current user.

For example, suppose `user_1` belongs to `group_1`, and `user_2` belongs to `group_2`.  If `user_1` pings my `LIST USERS` endpoint I want to get:

```
[{'groups': [1], 'username': 'user_1'}, {'groups': [], 'username': 'user_2'}]
```

Note that although `group_2` exists, it is not listed under `user_2`'s groups, because `user_1` is not in it.

Thoughts so far:

- Overloading `to_representation` seems like it will just change how the group is shown in the list of groups, not whether it is shown at all
- There are [some](https://medium.com/django-rest-framework/limit-related-data-choices-with-django-rest-framework-c54e96f5815e) [guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947143/how-to-programmatically-provide-queryset-to-primarykeyrelatedfield-in-drf-3) about how to filter the writable `group` choices here, meaning that `user_1` couldn't, for instance, add itself to `group_2`
- There are [some](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) [guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625805/djangorestframework-filtering-in-a-related-field) about how to filter for a read-only field
- I could combine the above two and do a read-only field and a write-only field, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950956/drf-simple-foreign-key-assignment-with-nested-serializers) for a different problem, but I'd rather not.

I don't see any guides on how have a single read/write `RelatedField` filtered by the current user.  **Any ideas?**

---

My code:

```
# serializers.py, vanilla
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'groups')


# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework import viewsets
from app import serializers

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)

# serializers.py, with write-choice filter modification
class FilteredRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        user_groups = user.groups.values_list('id', flat=True)
        queryset = Group.objects.filter(id__in=user_groups)
        return queryset

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = FilteredRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'groups')


# serializers.py, with read-only filtering
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'groups')
    def get_groups(self, instance):
        instance_user_groups = instance.groups.values_list('id', flat=True)
        current_user_groups = self.context['request'].user.groups.values_list('id', flat=True)
        return [x for x in instance_user_groups if x in current_user_groups]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing.  I think it works decently but if anyone has another idea please do jump in.

The thing holding me back was a mistaken assumption about how `to_representation` works.  What I wanted was to change the representation (in this case, by filtering a list) for an object that I do know I want to show in some form.  If I wanted to not show that object at all, that's best handled in the views.

`to_representation` sets the representation for any single object.  I wanted to filter a list attribute, so I overloaded `to_representation` to do that:

```
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['groups'] = [x for x in representation['groups'] if x in [some_arbitrary_list_to_filter_against]]
        return representation
```

This filters out for reading.  To make the filter work for read/write, make sure the many-to-many field is a custom subclass of `RelatedField` as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947143/how-to-programmatically-provide-queryset-to-primarykeyrelatedfield-in-drf-3).